# Removing Dots from starting of lines on NotePad++

Tags: notepad++

I have this situation

. . .     public void onClick(Widget sender) {

. . . .       PreferencesWidget.this.callback.onSuccess(feed.getText());

. . . .        hide();

}

How to remove this dots only

Note* there are spaces between dots

Answer (score 6):

It is possible that you have an option turned on that makes whitespace "visible" in the editor.

Try to toggle the menu option `View` -> `Show Symbol` -> `Show Whitespace and Tab`.

Answer (score 0):

`View` -> `Show Symbol` -> `Show Indent Guide`

Comment: I think the reporter is talking about whitespaces not indent.